# When i marinate pork with spices and vinegar , can i also add the sauted onion paste overnight with it?

Tags: spices, pork, onions, vinegar, marination

When making pork vindaloo the recipe says to marinate the pork OVERNIGHT with a mix of spices ( fried and made into a paste with a tablespoon Vinegar ) , the second part is to saute onions till they are golden brown and the add the pork. My doubt is , can i saute the onions and make it into a paste and add it with the overnight marination , will it spoil the taste or will it better it ? Thank you ! You guys are awesome !

Comment: It will essentially be a different dish. Whether it will be better or not is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The separation of the processes is about the chemical reaction between the spices and the pork first. The onions add a different set of chemicals and oils that are unwanted during the marination process. So, no, the taste will probably be different as the onions will change texture overnight, and the addition of the chemicals and flavors from the onions will change the flavors that are absorbed into the meat.

Comment: Just cast my mind back to a previous experience making Chicken Dopiaza... If left too long to marinate, the onion mixture will make the chicken less palatable.